# Drupal 7. Clearing cache disables my administrative rights

Tags: caching, permissions, drupal-7

I don't know when or how this happened, but if I go to "admin/config/development/performance" and click on "clear all caches", I get the green notification that my cache has been cleared, but also a notice saying "You do not have any administrative items" and the page is completely empty now. If I now try to visit "admin/config" that page is also empty. I also loose my ability to edit any blocks on the page.

I'm still logged in though.

It doesn't matter if I log out and in again, or try to log in with another browser, or flush my caches, the site won't let me access these parts after a clear all caches has been made. I need to backup my database to get my rights back.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What happens if you clear the cache using drush?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my case, the folder 'ctools' within my plugins directory did not have the correct permissions set. It took a while to track down this problem since I was not getting any notices or warnings about this.